# Questions about insects eating flour and living in the cracks of a wooden cutting boards

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, food, pest-control

I have a large wooden cutting board which is used in my kitchen mainly for preparing egg pasta. The wood type is *Populus* (poplar or aspen or cottonwood).

The main ingredients used with the cutting board are: flour (mainly soft wheat flour), hens' eggs, white sugar, butter, and baking powder.

After the food preparation, the cutting board is cleaned by scraping away the ingredients remains.

The board has some cracks and some small unknown insects are living inside the cracks.

The board has also a lot of holes due to woodboring beetles but I think the woodworms operated long time ago and they no longer live in the cutting board.

The unknown insect has an approximate length of 1 mm (along the direction of their movements) and a width of 0.3 mm. The unknown insects do not have wings, they just walk. I am not able to see how many pairs of legs they have.

The color of the insect is pale brown.

The cutting board was free from these unknown insects some months ago but then they appeared.

My questions:

1. What insects are they?
2. Are these insects poisonous to humans?
3. How can I get rid of them?

**Update**

The unknown insects could be *Acarus siro*, I will try to get a picture of the insects.

**Update 2**

Here is a picture. The bottom part of the image is a one Euro coin, the top part of the image is a caliper (each bright area is one mm tick).
[image]

Some more pictures:

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show an image of the beetles?

Comment: @Chris There are no woodboring beetles in the cutting board, there are just their holes. Unfortunately I do not have a suitable camera equipment to take a picture of the unknown insects I am asking about, they are too small (1mm x 0.3mm).

Comment: Buy a new cutting board. :P (plastic ones would solve all your problems). We can't ID a bug without a picture, either.

Comment: It sounds like a flour beetle, try the red (or rust red) flour beetle, though they are more than 1mm in length. You can probably kill them by putting your cutting board in the oven at 250° for an hour or two.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Does the flour beetle have wings?

Comment: @anongoodnurse I treat them with Ethanol 95% so, at least, they will get drunk :-)

Comment: No, the flour beetles are flightless. If you look at google's images (there are three main kinds of flour beetles; red is the lightest), you should be able to tell, especially from the head shape, which it is, if any.

Comment: @anongoodnurse [Red flour beetles are not flightless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_flour_beetle). Beetles have their flight wings hidden under a protective shell that is made from specialized wings. Also, flour beetles are a potential source of allergens, so if you're making these noodles for other people, I'd get a new cutting board. If you're the only one eating the noodles and aren't allergic to the beetles, it's up to you.

Comment: @user137 - you're correct. It's the confused flour beetle, which it closely resembles, that can't fly. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: That picture does not look like a flour beetle. Almost looks like a termite. Don't know if the size is consistent with termites.

Comment: The pictures aren't very good, but just for the sake of it I'm going to put [Springtail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Springtail) (Collembola, primitive hexapod) out there as well. It fits well size-wise (<6 mm, often less than 1 mm) and they have quite diverse morphologies. However, they are connected to moist environments, and it seems unlikely that a cuttingboard would be the main point of infestation. They might hide in cuttingboard cracks thought. It's not the *Acarus siro* from your update 2 (eight legged mite)

Comment: I agree with @user137 that termite is a possibility (antennae look a bit off though). It is definitely not a flour beetle.

Comment: Neither flour beetles nor termites get that small.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a **species of psocid** (of the family ***Psocoptera*, AKA booklice**).

[image: Psocid 1]
[image: Psocid 2]

Species are best differentiated by their abdominal structure and antennae. Without a better (more magnified) image and info about the OP's location, identification to species is not possible. Though its small size will definitely narrow the options.

If I had to guess based on the limited detail (and my limited knowledge), I'd say it's a species in the genus ***Liposcelis*** or related genera.  See Oklahoma State's ENTOPLP [ID key](http://entoplp.okstate.edu/profiles/go/psocid/p_key.html) for examples and info. I've included 2 random images of *Liposcelis* species for reference: the (TOP) is *Liposcelis brunnea* and (BOTTOM) is *Liposcelis corrodens*.

You can find info about prevention and removal from [Oklahoma state](http://entoplp.okstate.edu/profiles/go/psocid/facts.html), [King's College London](https://www.kcl.ac.uk/ip/bryanturner/other/home_psocids.html) or [the Orkin man](http://www.orkin.com/other/psocids/).

**UPDATE:** Though I, myself, cannot identify this psocid to species, according to this KCL [article](https://www.kcl.ac.uk/ip/bryanturner/other/psocid%20_0utlook.html), ***Liposcelis bostrychophila*** is the most likely candidate. [See [here](http://entoplp.okstate.edu/profiles/go/psocid/L_bost.html) for ID notes].

[image: Liposcelis bostrychophila]

From the KCL article:

> *Liposcelis bostrychophila* is the principal psocid pest species in the UK and in Europe. This single species, which is mainly an inhabitant of households, is responsible for virtually all of the psocid related complaints in the UK (Turner & Ali 1996)...Recent estimates are that 30% of households contain this species.
>
> Several other small (about 1mm long), flattened, wingless liposcelid species (eg. *Liposcelis corrodens*, *L. pearmani* and *L. brunnea*) can become quite common in industrial sites, particularly in the summer months but are uncommon in domestic premises.

Comment: The insects are in the northern part of Italy.

Comment: @AlessandroJacopson: Thanks for the location update. Though after reexamining your low-resolution photos closer I don't believe they contain the detail necessary  to identify this psocid to species. I think this might be the best ID you will receive. If you're satisfied, please accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I agree with the ID (and have upvoted) but, just for the record, this could be improved by responding to "How can I get rid of them?" within the body of the answer (you use an external link for this) and also by addressing "Are these insects poisonous to humans?".