# Bedbug or psocid?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I’ve found a few of these tiny bugs on the windowsill next to my bed. Can anyone tell if it is a bedbug nymph, psocid, or something else?? I’m hoping it’s not the former!

Edit: They were very small maybe 1 to 2 mm

[image: cropped]

[image: cropped]

Comment: I edited your images to get rid of 99% of the empty area. Can you mention roughly how large these were? There were no identifiable objects in the photos to estimate a size from. *Thanks!*

Comment: See [Insect identification - Is this a bedbug?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/56200/insect-identification-is-this-a-bedbug/56204#56204) and [Questions about insects eating flour and living in the cracks of a wooden cutting boards](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21864/questions-about-insects-eating-flour-and-living-in-the-cracks-of-a-wooden-cuttin/42117#42117) for a comparison.

Comment: Also, please update your post with your geographical location (i.e., what city/country are you in?). All species ID posts should be as detailed as possible to ensure you receive the best and most accurate answer.