# Is this a bedbug?

Tags: entomology, species-identification

Does anyone know if this is a bedbug? Or maybe a cockroach? I am located in Quebec, Canada.

If you need a clearer picture I'll try to take one without the glass in the way so my camera can focus better. Hopefully it doesn't escape.

[image]

Comment: where are you? country/state?

Comment: This is a woodlouse (often called a "pill bug" or "rolly polly"). See [this answer](http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/56204/16866) for an example of an actual bed bug.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I can see 5 extremities sticking out under the shield on one side in your image. Hence I think it has a total of 10 extremities. A bedbug, belonging to the class of [insects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insect), should have just 6.

I'm pretty sure it's a **[pill bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armadillidiidae)** (Fig. 1), a family of woodlice (***[Armadillidiidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armadillidiidae)***), belonging to the [*isopoda*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isopoda), an order of *[crustaceans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crustacean)*. *Crustaceans* include the lobsters, crabs and crayfish, to name a few.

[image: pill bug]
<sup>Fig. 1. A Pill bug species. source: [Natural History of Orange County](http://nathistoc.bio.uci.edu/crustacea/Isopoda/Pill%20bug.htm), CA</sup>

A bed bug is an **[insect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insect)** and has six extremities (Fig. 2).

[image: Bed Bug]
<sup>Fig. 2. A bed bug species. source: [Terminix](https://www.terminix.com/blog/diy/signs-your-room-has-bed-bugs)</sup>

So long story short, your species here is not an insect, and hence not a bed bug.

From the limited amount of information you've provided a specific species determination is difficult; there are many pill bugs.

Comment: Thank you! After going through some pictures of the different species of pill bugs, I have found a match.

Comment: Do you any special reason to say pill bug? From the unclear picture I find that hard so say. It's clearly a woodlouse though.

Answer (score 5):

No, it looks like a **woodlouse**. They are perfectly harmless to humans, and feed on decaying plant matter. They are also called isopods, roly-polies, or pill bugs.

[Woodlouse on Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodlouse)