# I found a bug on my bedroom floor. Is this a bedbug?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, pest-control

[image]

I found this insect on my bedroom floor. I'm worried. I hope this is not a bed bug.

Size: 3-4 mm

Comment: It doesn't really look like a bedbug, but the picture is extremely poor and you need a better one for a species determination.

Comment: Honestly i just want to know if this is a bed bug or not

Comment: It vaguely looks like a flea, but the photo quality is very poor.

Comment: Please update the question with your location

Comment: I've voted to reopen because I've incorporated some more info into the question AND I have a good answer for the user.

Comment: I think the question should remain closed - the pic is too poor for an ID with any certainty. Given the info, it might be a bed bug, but it could also be something else (so it is *unclear*).

Comment: I trust @theforestecologist has a good answer, so I voted to re-open.

Comment: @fileunderwater. The body shape (and, importantly, the presence of a notch at the pygidium) is a giveaway to the type of insect. Bed bugs do not have that body structure. It's a terrible picture, but I'm pretty sure I know it.

Comment: @theforestecologist This is up to the community, not up to me (and several have voted to keep closed). **I** don't think it should be open, since it is of extremely limited value to the site. I don't really see how we can have any pretence of maintaining the quality of BioSE if we keep this kind of question open. And whether you think that you can provide an answer doesn't really have anything to do with it; somebody can always imagine that they can provide some sort of answer to all questions that we close as "*too broad*" or "*unclear*". That doesn't mean that the Q should be open.

Comment: @theforestecologist Anyway, now it is open, so you got your wish. This is more of a discussion for meta though. For the record, I've been talking to an expert on domestic pest insects, and he thought that it is impossible to say for certain whether this is a bed bug (from this picture). This was also my original point, and why I think that the question should be closed (it is too *unclear* to answer with any certainty).

Comment: @Virginia Again, please update with your location. Also please let us know 1. if you have seen any more of these (if so, where? and do you have photos), 2. if you have pets and 3. if you have received any bug bites.

Answer (score 14):

To answer your question this is very likely NOT a bedbug.

- See [this answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/56204/16866) for a positive ID of (and more info for) a bedbug.

However, based on the size and body shape of your specimen, it appears you've found *another* blood sucking paristic pest: **a [flea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flea).**

[image: https://cdn.instructables.com/F53/PUTI/G6MPPPSN/F53PUTIG6MPPPSN.MEDIUM.jpg]

[image: Flea combo Pic]

<sup>Sources: [Here](http://www.domyownpestcontrol.com/images/content/flea%205.jpg), [here](http://fleascience.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/flea-top.png) and [here](http://www.three-little-pitties.com/images/fleaonfinger.jpg).</sup>

#### General Info:

- Fleas are small flightless parasitic insects (order [Siphonaptera](https://projects.ncsu.edu/cals/course/ent425/library/compendium/siphonaptera.html)) that consume the blood of mammals (including humans) and birds.
- Over 2,500 species of fleas have been described worldwide.
- Adults are 1.5-3.3mm long, narrower than wide and brown (or reddish brown). [[1](https://www.terminix.com/blog/diy/how-to-tell-if-you-have-bed-bugs-or-fleas),[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flea)]
- Flea larvae are worm-like (vermiform) in shape with a sparse covering of bristles.  They rarely live on the body of their host.  Instead, they are usually found in its nest or bedding where they feed as scavengers on organic debris (including adult feces).

  [image: flea and larvae]

#### Likely Species:

- I'm assuming you have a pet (cat or dog perhaps). If that is the case, you're likely looking at a [cat flea](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/urban/occas/catflea.htm) or [dog flea](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/urban/occas/dogflea.htm) (depending on your locaiton). From [UF IFAS](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/urban/occas/catflea.htm):

  > The most common [American] flea is the **cat flea, *Ctenocephalides felis***  (Bouché). The adult cat flea, unlike many other fleas, remains on the host. Adults require a fresh blood meal in order to reproduce.
  >
  > The **dog flea, *Ctenocephalides canis*** (Curtis), appears similar to the cat flea, but is rarely found in the United States. Cat fleas are commonly found on both cats and dogs in North America, while dog fleas are found in Europe.
  >
  > The two species are distinguished by a slight morphological difference which is detectable only under high magnification.

  [image: http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/urban/occas/cat_flea01.jpg]

  <sup>Cat flea (*Ctenocephalides felis*) from University of florida [IFAS](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/urban/occas/catflea.htm)</sup>

  Note: both species will parasitize multiple species (including both cats *and* dogs as well as humans), and their distinction (as mentioned above) is more dictated by geographic location. However, both can be found worldwide.

  [image: cat flea life cycle]

[Linardi & Santos (2012)](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?pid=S1984-29612012000400002&script=sci_arttext)<sup>1</sup> have an excellent publication for correctly identifying between the dog and cat flea.

---

**For More General Information See:**

<sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flea)
 - [Terminix](https://www.terminix.com/blog/diy/how-to-tell-if-you-have-bed-bugs-or-fleas)
 - [Orkin](http://www.orkin.com/other/fleas/fleas-life-cycle/)
 - [Univ. of Evansville](http://faculty.evansville.edu/de3/b43403/PDFs/37_Fleas.pdf)
 - [Purdue University](https://extension.entm.purdue.edu/publichealth/insects/flea.html)
 - UFL IFAS ([cat fleas](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/urban/occas/catflea.htm) or [dog fleas](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/urban/occas/dogflea.htm))</sup>

---

#### Fleas vs. Bed Bugs

See this [Terminix](https://www.terminix.com/blog/diy/how-to-tell-if-you-have-bed-bugs-or-fleas) page for "**What is the difference between bed bugs and fleas?**"

[image: https://fleasandbugs.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/bed-bugs-or-fleas.jpg]

[image: https://www.clipartsgram.com/image/420238766-bed-bugs-vs-fleas-table.jpg]

**Your specimen is almost certainly a flea because:**

1. The body of the insect in your picture is thin but vertically "tall" (or "laterally flattened"). In other words, it appears to be narrow like a flea.

   - A bed bug, on the other hand, is wide and vertically very [flat](http://www.greentechheat.com/images/bed-bug-adult-info.jpg).

     - Though, an engorged adult *can* appear to be more narrowly long when engorged on blood. See [here](http://www.achooallergy.com/blog/images/bed-bug-closeup.png).
   - Fleas are narrow so that they can easily maneuver through a host's fur/hair/feathers; while a bedbug is flat to be able to effectively hide in crevices.
2. The size (3-4 mm) is more appropriate for a flea.

   - Although some [larval stages](http://www.atcpestcontrol.com/uploads/2/0/6/7/20675874/3567985_orig.png) of bed bugs can range between 2.5 - 4 mm, these larval stages still retain the relatively flat appearance of the adult (except when engorged).
3. Notice the reflection toward the posterior end of the specimen in your photo. This is not present on bed bugs. This light is reflecting off the flea's [pygidium](http://faculty.evansville.edu/de3/b43403/PDFs/37_Fleas.pdf) (or sensilium).

   [image: flea pygidium]
4. Some fleas have [bristles on the posterior end of their body](http://blog.deanandadie.net/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/catflea1.jpg). Bed bugs do not. The insect in your picture has these posterior "hairs."
5. Fleas have powerful hind legs for [jumping](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F0e0CEiGfOk) that stay relatively close to the body, while bed bugs have very skinny legs that spread laterally from the body.

   - When bedbugs become engorged and appear more like the insect in the question picture (i.e., not flat), their abdomen grows posteriorly but their legs [do not extend very far back](http://www.bed-bugs-handbook.com/images/adults.jpg).
   - Notice when I brighten the OP's picture from the question you can see the light reflecting on the wide posterior [femur](http://media3.s-nbcnews.com/j/MSNBC/Components/Photo/_new/110210-science-flea-1130p.grid-6x2.jpg) that is both close to the body and extends relatively posteriorly as compared to the overall abdomen:

   [image: Flea evidence]
6. Location & Behavior: Although both fleas and bedbugs are generally nocturnal, both can be found during the day. However, they would generally be found in different places:

   - Bed bugs are likely to be digesting meals on the piping of your mattress, in and around the bed frame or box spring, along the baseboards and creeping around in other well-hidden cracks and crevices
   - Fleas, however, (like your specimen) are more likely to be found making themselves at home in animal sleeping areas or lurking around in your upholstery or carpeting, waiting to hop on for a bite. [[Source](https://www.terminix.com/blog/diy/how-to-tell-if-you-have-bed-bugs-or-fleas)]

---

**Should You Still be Concerned?**

- Some fleas are well known to transmit diseases (e.g., plague, murine typhus, etc., and a host of issues for your pets) unlike bedbugs. So really, fleas could potentially be more harmful.

  - Unlike bedbugs, however, [vacuuming](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/urban/occas/dogflea.htm) goes a long way for managing fleas on bedding, carpets, and furniture.
  - However, one flea can lay between 150 and 300 eggs every week, so do not wait!

---

<sup>Works Cited:</sup>

1  <sup>Linardi, P.M. and Santos, J.L.C., 2012. Ctenocephalides felis felis vs. Ctenocephalides canis (Siphonaptera: Pulicidae): some issues in correctly identify these species. Revista brasileira de parasitologia veterinária, 21(4), pp.345-354.</sup>

Comment: Wow, you did have a good answer!

Answer (score 2):

I had a bed bug infestation a few months ago. That picture looks like it could be a bed bug that hasn't fed in a while. But, the overall body shape looks more like a flea....

Bed bugs look different depending on what stage of life they are and whether or not they have fed recently. The picture below is a bed bug who has recently fed. You'll notice his body is fat and has a reddish color.

[image]

You may want to get an ultraviolet flashlight and look in the seams of your mattress and in the cracks of your headboard. Baby bed bugs are tiny and almost impossible to see..... Also, in case you have fleas, use that UV Flashlight to scan your carpets and pet's fur also.

You can find more information on how to find out if you have bed bugs and what you can do to eliminate them at http://ridbedbugsnow.com/how-to-get-rid-of-bed-bugs