# Is this a bed bug?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

This insect is ~7mm long, it has a dark strip on the body and I found it in Spain. Is it a bed bug?
[image: Pic1]
[image: Pic2]

Comment: See [this thread](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/56200/insect-identification-is-this-a-bedbug) for a genuine bed bug; given the less than ideal focus of your photographs I can't do more than guess at what you actually have, beyond "probable Heteroptera nymph" (a bed bug it isn't).

Comment: Looks the wrong colour to be a bed bug to me, they've been reddish brown when I've caught them (3 times in the last 5 months in India)...

Answer (score 2):

For me I think it is a nymph of [Centrocoris variegatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrocoris_variegatus). But I am not 100% sure beacause the photos are unclear. The facts lead us to that Heteroptera species, and surely it isn't a bed bug. Also here are and some photos of a nymph and of an adult Centrocoris:

**Nymph-to-adult:**

[image]

**Adult**:

[image]

I hope I covered your question! :)