# Is this a bed bug or some other bug?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

This white/yellowish bugs are crawling over my walls under cracks and below my wardrobe. I am not sure if they are bed bugs or some other bugs, there are very small in size thus I zoomed very much on the photograph, I hope someone would be able to assist me on identifying the bug.[image]!

Comment: This isn't a bed bug (see [this page](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/56200/insect-identification-is-this-a-bedbug) for the genuine article); I'm sure it's a book louse, but can't go further than that without a better picture; you should probably add the "entomology" tag to your question as well.

Comment: @ArthurJFrost I agree. It is a psocopteran. I am guessing that the post is more about worrying if it is a bedbug than precise identification. You should post your answer. : )

Comment: definitely a psocopteran. Not a bed bug.