# Bug species identification

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]Found this bug in my bed. Don't think it's a bed bug. Pretty small but fat and round and had deep reddish coloring.

Comment: That's a bed bug who drunk blood.

Comment: Are you sure? I checked my entire mattress and couldn't find any other bugs.

Comment: No. That's definitely not a bed bug. See [this post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/56204/16866) for detailed image/description of bed bugs. Among other obvious clues, bed bugs do not have long antennae like the insect in the OP's picture.

Comment: @Torqk Please provide information regarding your location and the size of the insect. Without that information, it will be difficult to provide an accurate ID. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That is **not a bed bug**. The picture is rather poor, which makes an ID difficult, but I think it might be the beetle [*Ptinus fur*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptinus_fur) (spider beetle), or another species from the same genus. This species is found all over the world, and often indoors (they can e.g. feed on dry foods).

Reasons for this suggestion is the body shape (incl relatively hidden head), color ("reddish"),long legs with thick femurs, long hind legs, and long antenna. The long legs together with the long antenna (the antenna can look similar to a fourth set of legs), as well as the hidden head (so the body look two-segmented) is what makes it look somewhat like a spider .

[image]
(picture from [bugguide.net](https://bugguide.net/node/view/88327))

[image]
(from [weedimages.com](https://www.weedimages.org/browse/detail.cfm?imgnum=5460359))