# Is this a bedbug? Found in my bathtub

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found this bug crawling in my bathtub [image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it seems like bedbug. If you want to make it certain put it on your skin and let it suck some blood. After sometime kill that bug by pressing it against your nails. If your nail is smelling awkward then it is definitely a bed bug.

Try comparing your bug against [this post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/56200/insect-identification-is-this-a-bedbug).