# Is this bedbug or book louse?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]
Hello everyone.
I have been seeing tiny critters like this one in bed and I started to worryif they are bed bugs. Although they seem different in appearance as well as the fact that they don't seem to bite, I wanted to be sure.
Sorry if the pic is a bit hazy, they are only about 1mm long.
I also did have a bit of a humidity issue since the roof was leaky. 
Does anyone know how to get rid of them. I tried different insecticides around the bed and on wooden part of the bed but nothing works.
Could they have settled in my new mattress? :([image]

Comment: this is almost certainly a book louse (aka a psocid). Definitively not a bed bug. See [Insect identification - Is this a bedbug?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/56204/16866)

Answer (score 5):

The pictures aren't very clear, but I would put this down as a book louse, not a bed bug nymph, as the body is quite elongated, which is atypical of the bed bugs and more typical of book lice.

#### Book louse:

[image: Book louse]

#### Bed bug:

[image]

Courtesy of  [bedbugger.com](https://bedbugger.com/2008/03/04/book-lice/).

Check out also [this page](https://apps.extension.umn.edu/garden/diagnose/insect/indoor/beetles/small/booklouse.html) from the University of Minnesota Extension; the picture nicely matches the photo you posted in body shape.

Comment: Not book louse.

Comment: Yes the OP's specimen is most likely a book louse. @totaredom, I agree with your post. As a side note: your source is not very reliable, and I would suggest avoiding its strict usage for support for an answer. Many more reputable resources exist that could more adequately corroborate your answer.

Comment: @theforestecologist Yeah, thanks for pointing out.  Was in a bit of a hurry, I'll admit.

Comment: Great update with a reputable source. Thanks. +1

Comment: @Muze then what is it by you? Bed bug?