# Are they bed bugs?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found these two bugs. I know that my pictures are not fully clear, but could they be bed bugs? One was found on the wall between my bedroom door and the other one trap in a Cochrane trap beside my TV in my living room. So far, I haven't seen any bites on my skin. But, I have to admit that I feel very concerned.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insect identification - Is this a bedbug?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/56200/insect-identification-is-this-a-bedbug)

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! We encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). At a minimum please first search on this site for similar questions before posting. ——— Thank you for taking the [tour], but please also go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: I did, but I would need more help.

Comment: Hi, and welcome!  Would it be possible to post some clearer pictures?  These pictures are not really detailed enough to allow for a positive identification.  Thanks!

Comment: I suspect your "Cochrane trap" is a "**cockroach** trap".

Comment: In the cockroach trap is a cockroach. I agree. However for the other (which the unclear picture) I'm still afraid of having to deal with a bed bug. I used permethrin product and the bug almost didn't move at all. If it would have been a cockroach, it should have been killed instantly and fall on the floor, shouldn't it? But I check my bed with a flash flight this night and I saw nothing. No bite either. I'm living in Ottawa. So, today, I've opened my bedroom window. I hope that the cold could slow down a possible infestation.

Comment: If you think they're different types of insects, you'll have to provide a clearer picture I'm afraid. The one on the wall doesn't look to me like a bed bug because it doesn't have a clearly defined neck.

Comment: Great thank you very much! I hope not to have the opportunity to provide you another picture. But you're reassuring me, and I'm very grateful to you. I checked my bed sheet and there's still no trace of bed bugs. I'm keeping my eyes widely opened and I will share with you if there's something new. Thanks'once again.

Answer (score 1):

They look to me like cockroach nymphs (newly hatched cockroaches). Note the long antennae (more than body length) and the two short protuberances at the rear. Also note that bed bugs have a head distinct from the body, whereas cockroaches have a head that blends into the body.

[3 mm cockroach nymph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockroach#Reproduction) (from Wikipedia)

[image: 3 mm cockroach nymph]

[A bed bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bed_bug#Insect) (from Wikipedia)

[image: A bed bug]

See also [this Q&A](https://www.whatsthatbug.com/2011/08/09/cockroach-nymphs-not-bed-bugs/) on What's That Bug.