# Is this a bed bug

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I'm moving into a new house. We have pretty much thrown out all of the bed furniture's and have not seen any bugs in the sheets or anything like that.  But, while preparing for painting, I saw this little guy on the wall and I've never seen one of those before.  Know what it is?  Is it a bed bug?

The plastic thing you see here is an electrical outlet wall plate. I would say the insect is about 2 mm. I live in Quebec, Canada

(Edit: i understand there is [another post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/56200/insect-identification-is-this-a-bedbug) like mine but his pictures show an adult bed bug while my pictures show what I think is either a nymph or a book lice or something else). Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insect identification - Is this a bedbug?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/56200/insect-identification-is-this-a-bedbug)

Comment: Size, shape, and coloration make me thing psocid (or book louse), but your pictures aren't too great. If you can, try uploading a better photo and you'll likely get a more definitive answer. If that's not possible, then I would recommend searching our site for other posts about psocids which will result in quite a few hits for you to compare images to. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I'll look for that, never heard of those!