# Bed bug or booklouse?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

I found this creature climbing on the lower part of a wall inside apartment. Can you distinguish if it's a bed bug nymph or a booklouse? Sorry the photo quality isn't great, because it's so small (2 mm). Thanks in advance! [image]

Comment: See [Insect identification - Is this a bedbug?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/56204/16866) for more information about bed bugs

Answer (score -1):

After looking it up, I can, with some confidence, confirm that this is a book louse in the larval stage, as seen in this picture:

https://bpca.org.uk/write/MediaUploads/Pages/A-Z/Booklice/booklice-1.jpg

I hope this answers your question!

Comment: you should add a link about bedbugs to ilustrate the difference of the two species.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bed_bug