# Is this a bed bug??? Small insect with tail thing found in bed

Tags: entomology

[image]

Couldn’t find any other ones, no bites, is very very very small like almost fruit fly size

Answer (score 0):

Nah, not a bedbug, those are round and weirdly flat, as shown in the photos in [the posting Tyersome linked](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/56200/insect-identification-is-this-a-bedbug).  What you have there is a beetle of some sort.  You can tell by the hard shell divided into two halves along the back - only beetles have those.  The wings are folded up underneath there.  I couldn't say what species of beetle exactly, there are many kinds of tiny brown beetle and the photo is fuzzy.  It's harmless, anyway, whatever it is.

Beetles have no tails.  Looking at the photo, I think what you thought was a tail is actually the end of its wing poking out from under its shell.  I often see that.

Update: I found this, which has photos that look a lot like yours.  One of the photos of one of the beetles even has a nub which looks a bit like a tail.

[UK Natural History Museum forum: Is this a biscuit beetle or furniture beetle?](https://www.nhm.ac.uk/natureplus/message/116202.html)

The rest of the above is from memory from reading wildlife books, but I was asked to provide some references so here are some websites that confirm the beetle facts I mentioned.

https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/blog/2017/11/common-uk-insect-identification/

http://www.oum.ox.ac.uk/thezone/insects/instant/index.htm

https://www.coleoptera.org.uk/beetle-morphology

https://www.coleoptera.org.uk/what-are-beetles