# Bug Identification - Is this a bed bug?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

What kind of bug is this? Side of a penny for size. Found on basement floor in a bedroom. Pleaase tell me this isn't a bed bug[image][image][image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insect identification - Is this a bedbug?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/56200/insect-identification-is-this-a-bedbug)

Comment: No not a bedbug. ID is impossible without a location in the world (e.g. nearest big city, state). Likely a weevil of some sort.