# Is this a bed bug? Looks like a skeleton

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

Is this a bed bug? Germany, the size of specimen is 0.6 mm.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insect identification - Is this a bedbug?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/56200/insect-identification-is-this-a-bedbug)

Comment: Please provide your location and approximate size of the specimen if you want an ID.

Comment: Looks similar to the picture in your answer, but I don't know. I have a new picture uploaded.

Answer (score 3):

The body shape, [cerci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cercus), size, and in-home concern have me thinking this is a cockroach nymph.

It doesn't resemble the nymph of any of the really common global pest species (e.g., German, Oriental, brown banded; [see here](https://www.domyown.com/images/content/life_cycle_of_different_types_of_roaches_3.jpg)), and narrowing down otherwise is difficult. I don't know the exact species (as my internet keeps crapping out when I search for European-based websites). So I will -- for now -- show you imagery of a nymph of a common pest cockroach for comparison:

[image]

<sup>[Pest Off Solutions](https://www.pestoffsolutions.com.au/blog/brown-banded-cockroach)</sup>