# Is this a bedbug or something else?

Tags: species-identification

Found it on my bedsheet close to my pillow.[image] My boyfriend had a couple of welts a few weeks ago on his chest, but we can’t seem to find any other evidence on the mattress or around it.

Comment: Welcome Mel. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for our guidelines as and when. Could you add some more detail such as what area of the world you might be in, if there was food involved nearby etc..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insect identification - Is this a bedbug?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/56200/insect-identification-is-this-a-bedbug)