# What type of bug is this? Found under a blanket

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I'm a bit worried as we found a few of these bugs under a blanket in a spare bedroom. It was very small (3-3.5 mm) and rust/brown in color with a tubular/long shape. There seemed to be a nymph next to it (looked like a small worm). I live in France and autumn is approaching. I could only decipher shape when zoomed in with a photo. Looks really small with the naked eye. I really hope this isn't a bed bug as I have been doing LOTS of global travel in the last 6 months.
Thanks for your expertise. I also found one crawling on the ceiling in the same room. Thank you for your expertise.[image]

[image]

Comment: @ commenters. Comments are not for answers. They cannot be downvoted if incorrect, which is especially problematic on species ID posts and even more so when most of the above comments are wrong. This is not a black beetle, is not a weevil, and is not a Cardinal beetle. It's more likely a pest (likely some type of grain beetle or related) that I *would* recommend the OP worry about.

Comment: Also, FYI: See [Insect identification - Is this a bedbug?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/56204/16866) for some images of bed bugs.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140064/discussion-on-question-by-francemama-what-type-of-bug-is-this-found-under-a-bla).